# Review Notification Indicator

Tags: support, review

I don't want to make too much of this, but more of just a suggestion.

Would it be at all possible to have some kind of indicator that there are new items that need to be reviewed..Example:

[image]

Instead of having to blindly refresh the page to see if anything new needs to be reviewed.

Comment: You get a number if there are more than 5 items pending review.

Comment: oh really? I didn't know that. It will show a 5 or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, the number of pending suggested edits is shown only if the count is more than 5. If it's more than 5, there'll be a total count of no of pending edits.

[image]

Comment: This only works for edits? why can't it work for any field, cause it doesn't work for me if there is 6 pending first posts. http://puu.sh/72qoG.png

Comment: It's intended to work only for suggested edits, those are the ones in most need of attention + fastest moving ones.